spring boot oauth2 authentication failed ROLE_ANONYMOUS
user login on /login, /login redireting user to oauth2 keycloak next(after successful login) keycloak redirecting user to /home but user is not authenticated. roles are not working too. /roleDebug return authority: [ROLE_ANONYMOUS], /loginDebug return User is not authenticated, /tokenDebug return NullPointerException
@RestController
public class DebugController {
    @GetMapping("/tokenDebug")
    public void tokenDebug(OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {
        if (authentication == null) {
            System.out.println("No authentication token found");
        }
        OAuth2User user = authentication.getPrincipal();
        System.out.println("Access Token: " + user.getAttributes().get("access_token"));
    }
    @GetMapping("/roleDebug")
    public void rD(){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println(auth);
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles = auth.getAuthorities();
        System.out.println("authority: " + roles);
    }
    @GetMapping("/loginDebug")
    public void getCurrentUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {
        if (authentication == null) {
            System.out.println("User is not authenticated");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(authentication.getPrincipal());
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth
                                .requestMatchers("/","/loginDebug" ,"/login","roleDebug","/tokenDebug").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/adminPanel").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                                .requestMatchers("/home").authenticated()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
                        oauth2Login
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home",true)
                );

        return http.build();
    }
}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8180/home
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/master
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.authorization-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.token-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs
server.port=8180
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=springClient
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=gJNj148Eukyqo5YEALZ805UXbz2fcsDp
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid,profile,email
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-info-authentication-method=form

  "Authorization": {
    "springClient": {
      "roles": [
        "ROLE_USER",
        "ROLE_ADMIN"
      ]
    },

token is working propertly. i have read spring boot search for roles in token/Authorization so changed resource_acces for Authorization(before it didn't work too)
i have tried change resource_access name for Authorization, change application.properties, implment jwt decoder,change securityFilterChain. i am expecting that after login(keycloak oauth2) user will rdirected to /home and will has Authorization

As of https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html
permitAll - The request requires no authorization 
and is a public endpoint; 
note that in this case, 
the Authentication is never retrieved from the session

